# custom server side validation c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to this and created a custom attribute for string length validation on the server side. For example i have this

```
 [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength", ErrormessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
 public string LastName { get; set; }
```

and i want to create a custom attribute, so i can reduce the duplicates everytime i need to validate the string length

```
[MyStringLength(5)]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

This is my view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
```

My code for custom attribute "MyStringLength"

```
 public class MyStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{

    public MyStringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength) : base(maximumLength)
    {         
        base.ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength";
        base.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource);
    }
}
```

This helped me [Modify default ErrorMessage for StringLength validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540314/modify-default-errormessage-for-stringlength-validation)
 but after i post the form it just refreshes the page with the values and doesn't show any validation message

Comment: You should provide your code with your attempt instead of relating another question claiming it didn't work. Maybe is your way of implementing it that didn't work.

Comment: What is `MyStringLengthAttribute`?

Comment: @RonBeyer It is the name of the custom attribute i created. This is my code                public class MyStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
    {

        public MyStringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength) : base(maximumLength)
        {         
            base.ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength";
            base.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource);
        }
    }

Comment: @Guilherme ty for taking the time. I edited my question to have the code of my custom attribute.

Comment: You need to register your attribute in `global.asax.cs` for it to be used.

Comment: You're missing the minimum length from your custom attribute, so you wouldn't see the error message if you were trying to trigger it with a 1 character string for example.

Comment: @NickCoad ty. i am concerned as to why the validation message isn't showing up if i entered more than 5 characters. minimum length isn't a concern as of now.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That helped. Thank You. i also needed an adapter to provide client validation rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed an adapter for client validation and register the custom attributes in my global.asax.cs. Please see [Client-side validation for custom StringLength validation attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173753/client-side-validation-for-custom-stringlength-validation-attribute)

Comment: You do not need an adaptor - there is already one built in. Its just `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(MyStringLength), typeof(StringLengthAttributeAdapter));`. And add the code in your answer, not a link

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't know why i didn't think about it. Thank You.